# How to make a linear gradient along curve?

Tags: inkscape, path, gradient

What I want to achieve is basically this:

[image]

a path with a gradient that goes transparent towards the sides.

What I **really** want, though, is that gradient to be linear. For the example above, I used a Gaussian Blur filter, which, by definition, isn't linear.

I also tried to make a small rectangle with a vertical linear gradient transparent-black-transparent and then applying it to the path, but it doesn't work, because objects cannot be put along paths, other paths can.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Why isn't a guassian blur suitable?  A gaussian blur added to a path is still editable as a vector path. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/U5eT80J) and the result is transparent.

Comment: I want to draw a path for a Thymio robot, it needs that specification.

Comment: Are you going to print the gradient path? There is a new swamp of nonlinear grayscale reproduction waiting for you.

Comment: I am going to print it, what are you speaking about?

Comment: Printers make grays by varying how big part of the paper is covered with opaque black ink. They can also try to layer overlapping cyan, magenta and yellow dots. In low cost home and office printers the user has very little of control over the process. You can have linear gradient onscreen but the print process can spoil it "for your best". Illustrator and Affinity Designer at least allow you to make arbitary gradients along a path. You can experiment which gradient is linear enough as printed. Rasterized gradient causes no extra harm because normal printers rasterize it in the printer driver.

Comment: (Continued) You can export the path to GIMP without any blur nor gradient, apply blur there  to a single layer where you path is as black on white and fix the gradient with the curves tool. Experiment which fix makes good result as printed and find if there's some greyscale reproduction options in the printer driver.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that!

Comment: I checked: I couldn't properly fix  a gaussian blur gradient to linear gradient with curves in a bitmap image editor. I inserted an answer.

Comment: A gradient along a path wouldn't give you a single drawable path either.  What are you actually trying to draw with the robot - a gradient or just the path?  I doubt very much if it would be able to draw a gradient, far less a blur. In software such as Illustrator even a gradient along a path is a raster effect.

Answer (score 3):

I guess blurring is a hopeless way to make trackable gradients for your robot experiments. You need something like this:

[image]

This is drawn with pattern brush which has a linear 3-stop gradient white-black-white. The screenshot is from Affinity Designer which allows any PNG image to be used as a brush.  The curve can be an arbitary path, you only apply the brush to it.

This functionality is available at least in Illustrator and Affinity Designer. Inkscape hasn't it.

In Inkscape you can try to apply Extension > Generate from path > Interpolate. In the next image it's applied to red instead of white or transparent for visibility only.

[image]

**In the left** there's a red path and its black duplicate with much narrower stroke.

**In the middle**: Apply stroke to path to the wider curve, remove the fill, insert a narrow stroke and separate the edges with Path > Break Apart.

In this phase you must cut the paths to open at the closest possible nodes. Insert new nodes if there is none nearby. Closed path will cause a mess due the unpredictable starting point. A mess is still possible due opposite path directions, but you can fix it with Path > Reverse if needed.

The wide red path can be originally open path - maybe the start and end nodes in the same place - the duplicate is automatically open, but you must delete with the node tool and DEL the end segments after converting the stroke to path.

**In the right** The black and the outer red paths are selected and extension Generate from Path > Interpolate is applied. Style is interpolated, too and there's 40 copies (=enough to fill gaps). Then the same is done for the black and the inner red paths. The extension leaves the originals intact, they can be accessed in the layers panel.